Creating a Universal Bootable Ubuntu 24 LTS for Bootit NG on any partition number
I'm currently working on preparing an Ubuntu 24 LTS that can be installed on any partition number and remain bootable, specifically to work with the Bootit NG boot manager (on Bios). Ubuntu works fine if it is on number one in the partition list, but if I put it on 2,3,4+ it wont boot anymore.
I've tried several approaches, especially with GRUB, but I encountered the following errors:
error: unknown filesystem. Entering rescue mode (when I moved ubuntu in the partition list)
ext2 does not support embedding (When i tried to install grub directly on the partition)
For context, the system is running on an ext4 formatted partition, Bios and multiple Windows OS. Managed by Bootit NG.
Here's what I've attempted so far:
Standard GRUB Installation: I used the usual GRUB installation commands (grub-install and update-grub), but I ended up with the errors mentioned above.
Bootit NG Settings: I ensured Bootit NG was correctly set up to recognize and boot from the partition where Ubuntu is installed.
Any advice or specific steps would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance for your help!

Ubuntu 24 would refer to a Ubuntu Core product. Ubuntu 24.04 is Ubuntu LTS version. Please always make sure the info in your question is accurate. Did you visit the Bootit NG web site and verify it works with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS?

UEFI or BIOS boot? Does Bootit NG support UEFI boot which all systems since 2012 are. If system before 2012 better to use a lightweight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors)

its Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, sorry i forgot to clarify. Im using BIOS for the system. Thank you for your help and advices. I will take look into the flavours.
